# TypeError: unbound method read() must be called with HTTPResponse instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and trying the below as a learning exercise.  I'm attempting to connect to random.org and print out a randomly generated integer and receiving the below error.  Why am I receiving this?

TypeError: unbound method read() must be called with HTTPResponse instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

```
import httplib

print "Fetching random number"

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.random.org")
conn.request("GET", "/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new")
r1 = httplib.HTTPResponse.read(1024)

print r1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the `read` method *unbound* on the class:

```
httplib.HTTPResponse.read(1024)
```

You need to call that method on the `HTTPResponse` instance returned by the `conn.request()` call instead:

```
response = conn.request("GET", "/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new")
r1 = response.read(1024)
```